# Jquery plugin for live validation without <form>-element?

Tags: jquery, validation

I've been looking at: 
1. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
2. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validator
3. plugins.jquery.com/project/validity

The first one looks great and I got it working when using forms. However I can't get it to work when I want it to be in a div instead. The reason is because we use jquery.post to post the input fields to the database and then getting id value back.

The second one says it supports validation without being in a form, but I can't get that plugin to work at all for me. And I couldn't find any proper documentation for it either.

The third one also looks great, but I can't get that to properly work either and it doesn't seem to support live feedback.

Is there something that I could change in the first plugin to not be dependent on forms? I tried to just do some search and replace for form and replace with div. But of course it isn't that simple.

So what I want:
* Jquery plugin for validation
* Provides live validation (as you type)
* NOT be dependent on having the input fields in a form. Should be able to just have them in a div

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not give some example code that explains the problems you're having instead of vaguely describing them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validator

It's author describes it as: "You can validate fields in a DIV **without** a FORM tag."

You can also try this: http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm